# sed multi line pattern

Tags: awk

I need to search for the following

```
[ec2_server]
server_host=something

[list_server]
server_host=old_name
```

to

```
[ec2_server]
server_host=something

[list_server]
server_host=new_name
```

Since the server name is in square bracket I had challenges with `sed` special characters. Also I cannot just search and replace `server_host`, it needs to be `list_server` host that needs to be changed. Its a multiline search and replace command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the first line after `[list_server]`:

```bash
awk '/\[list_server]/ { print; getline; $0 = "server_host=new_name" } 1'
```

###### Update

Here's how you can replace the value of a specific key in a specific section:

```bash
awk -v section='list_server' -v key='server_host' -v value='new_value' '
    /^\[/ {
        in_target_section = ( $0 ~ "^\\[" section "]" )
    }
    in_target_section && $0 ~ "^" key "=" {
        $0 = key "=" value
    }
    1
' conf.ini
```

<sup>**remark:** in the current code, `section` and `key` are regexps. If you prefer them to be literal strings then you'll have to prepend a `BEGIN` block where you escape them accordingly.</sup>

Comment: That works perfectly, but when I call from another bash file how do I in place replace like the -i option in sed

Comment: GNU awk 4.3+ have an option for that: `awk -i inplace '...' file.conf`. If you don't have it then you'll need to use the old standard way: `awk '...' file.conf > file.conf.new && mv file.conf.new file.conf`

Comment: we are parameterizing the search value and replacement values and couldnt get it working, Im trying it this way ```awk -v patt="[list_server]" -v parm="server_host" -v parmval="new_name" '/\patt/ { print; getline; $0 = parm=parmval } 1' dev.conf > dev.conf.tmp && mv dev.conf.tmp dev.conf```

Comment: see my update for their parameterization